# ValueError when calling a method

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a partial code that should be able to determine whether a parameter in some .c files is unused or not.

So first, it finds a parameter name and saves it as `theParam` and then `searchAndValueExtract` is called, where theParam is used as a search-word to search for parameters with identical names (and then reading their values)

```
import os
savedValue = ""
compareValue = ""
theParam = ""
usedParameters = list()
equalValueCounter = 0
parameterCounter = 0
emptyline = "" 

def searchAndValueExtract(theParam, compareValue, parameterCounter, savedValue):
        # when theParam has a value
        # this method will be called to find an identical parameter and then grab it's value for comparison
        for path, compdirs, compfiles in os.walk('C:/PATH'):
            for compfile in compfiles:
                if compfile.endswith('.c'):
                    with open(os.path.join(path, compfile), 'r') as r:
                        for line in r:
                            if '=' in line and theParam in line:
                                savedValue = value(row, line, savedValue, statements, cur)
                                compareValue = savedValue
                                parameterCounter += 1
                                return compareValue
        return parameterCounter

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/PATH'):
    for cFile in files:
        if cFile.endswith('.c'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, cFile), 'r') as this:
                for row in this:
                    if '=' in row and row != emptyline:
                        theParam = takeTheParam(row, theParam)
                        savedValue = value(row, savedValue, statements, cur, line)
                        while theParam not in usedParameters:  # Has the param already been checked?
                            safeValue = savedValue
                            compareValue, parameterCounter = \
                                searchAndValueExtract(theParam, compareValue, parameterCounter, savedValue)
                            if safeValue == compareValue:
                                equalValueCounter += 1
                                continue
                            else:
                                usedParameters.append(theParam)
                                break
                        else:
                            break
```

When compiling I get the error

```
File "C:/PATH/ParamChecker.py", line 82, in <module>
    searchAndValueExtract(theParam, compareValue, parameterCounter, savedValue)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I've searched around, but nothing has helped me understand it, or I am simply not grasping how the solution could be implemented in my case.

Comment: This is what happens when you put `a,b = fn()` but `fn()` only returns one value. E.g. `compareValue, parameterCounter = searchAndValueExtract(...)`

Comment: @khelwood - Please read my comment posted below.

Answer (score 2):

The function `searchAndValueExtract` returns a single value, yet you try to assign its return value to 2 variables.

```
def searchAndValueExtract(theParam, compareValue, parameterCounter, savedValue):
    ...
        return compareValue
    return parameterCounter

.
.
.

compareValue, parameterCounter = searchAndValueExtract(theParam, compareValue, 
                                                       parameterCounter, savedValue)
```

Comment: How should I solve it? `compareValue` is obviously getting returned far more often than `parameterCounter` - however I still want both of them to be returned when they are supposed to be used outside the method.